# How does the Visual Studio console decide how to represent non printable ascii characters?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, ascii

I am working with encodings.
My byte array contains ascii NULL (\0), END OF MEDIUM (\u0019) and FILE SEPARATOR (\001c).
([link](https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/%7Etomw/java/unicode.html#x0000))

`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesRequest)` manages to decode the characters into the below string:

\0\u0019_STACKO_001_55010\u001cB

[image]

Since those three characters are non printable, how does the VS console decide how to display these graphems?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: VS console doesn't, it's decided by the font.

Comment: It’s determined by the encoding used by the display, probably [code page 437](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any knowledge about the inner work of the console and I am working on my knowledge about Unicode, but this is what I have figured out so far.

### VS Console Properties

If you right-click on the console window’s header, you can select “Properties”. In the first tab (“Options”), you will find “Current character table”. On my computer it says “850 (OEM - …)”.  In US it is probably 437.

### Code page

The first part (0-127) of code page 850 is the same as in code page 437:

[Code page 437 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters)

Here you can find what symbol is used for the non-printable characters and the corresponding Unicode code point.

### Font

VS console is converting the control code to its corresponding Unicode code point described in code page 437.

The font that you have selected in the second tab in “Properties” (“Character”) is then responsible for the look of the symbol in the console. On my computer the “Consolas” is the default font.

If you select the “Lucida Sans Typewriter” as font, you will see boxes for the control characters since that font doesn’t have any glyph for the Unicode code points that is used for the control characters.

You can use the “Character map” to display the glyphs for an installed font in Windows.